# Multi-Threaded Prime number Finder in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a java program that I have to find all prime numbers and the count of the prime numbers up to 200 million. I have to use trial division with static global variable that all the threads share to hold the next number to be checked if prime. As it finds a prime it adds it to a array then displays the array upon completion. here is what I have so far and all my threads are showing the same number of primes found as the total number of primes can anyone help with this.

Main-

```
//*import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MultiThreadedPrimeFinder {
    static final int nThreads = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        int t;
        int total = 0;
        PrimeThread[] pthreads = new PrimeThread[nThreads];
        //*Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        //*System.out.println("Enter a Positive Integer: ");
        //*long num = kb.nextLong();
        long starttime, endtime, runtime, a = 0;
        starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i <10000000; i ++)
            a+=i;
        for (t=0; t<nThreads; t++)
        {
            pthreads[t] = new PrimeThread();
            pthreads[t].start();
        }

        for (t=0; t<nThreads; t++)
        {
            pthreads[t].join();
            System.out.println("Thread "+t
                    +"  Prime count: "+ pthreads[t].count);
        }
        total = PrimeThread.count;
        System.out.println("Total prime count: "+total);
        for (int i=0;i<100; i++)
            System.out.println(""+i+": "+PrimeThread.primes[i]);
        endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        runtime = endtime - starttime;
        System.out.println("The run time is " +runtime +" milliseconds");

    }

    }
```

Class -

```
public class PrimeThread extends Thread{
static long nextNumber=3;
static final long max = 1000;
public static int count=0;
public long thread = 100;
public static long[] primes = new long[100000]; 


public void run() {
    long myNumber;
    while ((myNumber=getNextNumber())<=max) {
        primes[0] = 2;
        if (prime(myNumber)) {

                primes[count++] = myNumber;
            }
        }
    }


public static synchronized long getNextNumber() {
    long n = nextNumber;
    nextNumber +=2;
    return n;
}

public boolean prime(long n) {
    int i;

    for (i=3; i * i<=n; i+=2)
        if (n%i==0) return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

the output looks like this

```
Thread 0  Prime count: 167
Thread 1  Prime count: 167
Total prime count: 167
0: 2
1: 5
2: 7
3: 11
4: 13
5: 17
6: 19
7: 23
8: 29
9: 31
10: 37
11: 41
12: 43
13: 47
14: 53
15: 59
16: 61
17: 67
18: 71
19: 73
20: 79
21: 83
22: 89
23: 97
24: 101
25: 103
26: 107
27: 109
28: 113
29: 127
30: 131
31: 137
32: 139
33: 149
34: 151
35: 157
36: 163
37: 167
38: 173
39: 179
40: 181
41: 191
42: 193
43: 197
44: 199
45: 211
46: 223
47: 227
48: 229
49: 233
50: 239
51: 241
52: 251
53: 257
54: 263
55: 269
56: 271
57: 277
58: 281
59: 283
60: 293
61: 307
62: 311
63: 313
64: 317
65: 331
66: 337
67: 347
68: 349
69: 353
70: 359
71: 367
72: 373
73: 379
74: 383
75: 389
76: 397
77: 401
78: 409
79: 419
80: 421
81: 431
82: 433
83: 439
84: 443
85: 449
86: 457
87: 461
88: 463
89: 467
90: 479
91: 487
92: 491
93: 499
94: 503
95: 509
96: 521
97: 523
98: 541
99: 547
The run time is 17 milliseconds
```

Comment: you have `public static int count=0;` this means that all threads have the same variable, of course it will be the same, how this code suppose to work?

Comment: it is supposed to be that each thread is testing a certain amount of numbers that is why I didn't get why they were all coming up with the same amount of primes

Comment: so, `count` variable should be NON static, but then you will have problems with `primes[count++] = `, here you should use another static variable with type `AtomicInteger`, and use it as `primes[totalCount.incrementAndGet()] = `

Comment: May I ask what the loop `for(int i = 0; i <10000000; i ++) a+=i;` is supposed to do? If it just adds all numbers from 0 to 10000000 you can use Gauss: a=(Math.pow(n,2)+n)/2; where n is 10000000 in your case.

Comment: So... I don't completely understand what the question is. Is it just about the static variable? It seems like 90% of the code is irrelevant here.

Comment: That for loop is a way to keep track of how many milliseconds my program runs because I have to keep track of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
public static int count=0;
```

which keeps track of the number of primes gotten in total. Since it's `static`, `pthreads[0].count == pthreads[1].count == PrimeThread.count`. To see the primes retrieved by the individual threads, add an instance counter:

```
public int myCount = 0;
....
primes[count++] = myNumber;
myCount++;
...
System.out.println("Thread "+t
        +"  Prime count: "+ pthreads[t].myCount);
```

Also, to prevent interleaving of count++, you should synchronize when incrementing it.

Comment: this will replace primes in `primes` array

Comment: @Lashane No. The original, static count variable is still used to ensure proper placement within the primes array. This code is tested working.

Comment: run and you will see that even if count is volatile - ++ is not atomic operation in java, this code will replace primes

Comment: @Lashane Actually you are right, marking it volatile will help but is insufficient. Edited. In any case, it's wholly irrelevant; this question is about getting the counts right, not about thread safety.

Comment: its ok, just one more thing - each thread put primes[0] as 2, which is not very correct, anyway - you're replacing this value right now )

Comment: @Lashane What do you mean by "I'm replacing this value right now"? I noticed the redundant setting of primes[0], but decided it was largely irrelevant, if the asker wanted better performance he'd be better off choosing a better algorithm for prime testing.

Comment: as soon as initial value for count is 0 - first iteration will replace primes[0] with some value, so it will replace number 2 in this array

Comment: Oh, that is a problem, but with the code the asker provided, and unrelated to the count; I could include it in my answer but the question was not "please search my program for all of its bugs." (that would be a bad question)

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I know there are a lot of flaws in my code, I am still learning the ins and outs of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you with the multi-threaded aspect, I found this page trying to solve something similar, but your prime finding algorithm has a couple of issues:

First off, in your `run()` method, why have the `primes[0] = 2` inside the while loop?  It's getting set each time when it only needs to get set once.

Second, you are skipping 3, which is a prime.  This is happening because you set `myNumber` to 3, but then call `getNextNumber()` before you check it.  Initialize `myNumber` to 1.

Answer (score -1):

Despite @Saposhiente answer is correct, I'd like to post proper version for OP to consider and find out other small problems

thread class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class PrimeThread extends Thread {
    final public static long[] primes = new long[100000]; 
    static {
        primes[0] = 2; // init 1st prime only 1 time
    };

    final static AtomicLong nextNumber = new AtomicLong(3L);
    final static long MAX = 1000L;

    public int count = 0; // non static local count
    public static AtomicInteger totalCount = new AtomicInteger(); // static global count

    public void run() {
        long myNumber;
        while ((myNumber = nextNumber.getAndAdd(2L)) <= MAX)
            if (prime(myNumber)) {
                primes[totalCount.incrementAndGet()] = myNumber; // note increment and get instead of get and increment
                count++;
            }
    }

    public static boolean prime(final long n) {
        final long maxI = (long) Math.sqrt(n); // faster than calculation of i*i each time
        for (long i = 3; i <= maxI; i += 2)
            if (n%i==0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

main program:

```
public class MultiThreadedPrimeFinder {
    static final int nThreads = 2;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final PrimeThread[] pthreads = new PrimeThread[nThreads];

        final long starttime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
            pthreads[i] = new PrimeThread();
            pthreads[i].start();
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
                pthreads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        final long endtime = System.nanoTime(); // measure only actual execution, without any system calls

        System.out.println("The run time is " + ((endtime - starttime) / 1000000L) + " milliseconds");

        for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
            System.out.println("Thread " + i + "  Prime count: " + pthreads[i].count); // output each thread's count
        System.out.println("Total prime count: " + PrimeThread.totalCount.get()); // output total count
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            System.out.println(""+i+": "+PrimeThread.primes[i]);
    }
}
```